# SQL conditional nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have query like:

```
select * 
from BASE_TABLE
inner join (
    select * from TABLE_A
) t on BASE_TABLE.ID = t.ID
```

and want to make nested query conditional, something like:

```
select * 
from BASE_TABLE
inner join (
    if @var = 1 
        select * from TABLE_A
    else 
        select * from TABLE_B
) t on BASE_TABLE.ID = t.ID
```

Is it possible?
Query is used inside stored procedure. Solution should work for SQL Server and Oracle or at least for SQL Server.

Comment: Have you read similar question on SO? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1850031/1083946.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  BASE_TABLE
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT col1, col2, colN FROM TABLE_A WHERE @var IN (1) -- "if"
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2, colN FROM TABLE_B WHERE @var IN (2) -- "else if"
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2, colN FROM TABLE_C WHERE @var NOT IN (1, 2) -- "else"
  ) t ON t.ID = BASE_TABLE.ID
```

Comment: Could you explain why union fits here. Does it work properly if 2 result sets have the same rows?

Comment: Union fits here because the `WHERE` clauses are mutually exclusive. I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: The fact that you asked this question in the first place indicates an error in the database design. In a well-designed database you should not have to "switch tables" in a query.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (but then you need to specify fields; you can't use `select *` syntax):

```
select base.ID, base.Field1, base.Etc, Field1 = case when @var=1 then a.Field1 else b.Field1 end,
       Field2 = case when @var=1 then a.Field2 else b.Field2 end
  from BASE_TABLE base
  left join TABLE_A a on base.ID = a.ID
  left join TABLE_B b on base.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below query

```
declare @var int=1  
declare @qry nvarchar(max)  
set @qry='select * from BASE_TABLE ('  
if @var=1  
set @qry=@qry+ 'select * from TABLE_A'  
else  
set @qry=@qry+ 'select * from TABLE_B'  

set @qry=@qry+')t on BASE_TABLE.ID = t.ID'

exec (@qry)
```